# Using NT Service to host Quartz.NET Scheduler

Tags: quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I'm currently looking at using an NT Service to host a Quartz scheduler instance.  *(I'm using an NT Service instead of IIS as the scheduler cannot be guaranteed to be up as IIS will periodically perform recycling.)*

The idea is that the service will start up, create a scheduler instance and refer to an XML file to start up a list of jobs (around 15).

**Problem**
I need to be able to send messages to the NT service to allow me to:

- Add new jobs
- Stop and Start Existing jobs
- Delete jobs

From what I've found, I'm pretty restricted here as I can only send an integer string to the service using the [OnCustomCommand](http://arcanecode.com/2007/05/30/windows-services-in-c-sending-commands-to-your-windows-service-part-7/) function of the service.  Additionally, this will limit me to values of 128 --> 256.  I hope to use values within this range to be interpreted by the service as scheduler commands (add, stop, start, and delete).  Each command would refer to a specific file that held the parameters necessary for each job.

Before going any further, does this sound like a reasonable approach.  Or, is it fraught with danger !!

Suggestions on this or a better approach are welcome.

Cheers,

Comment: Err, if you use Quartz.Net in a NT service, why don't you simply access it via remoting to add/remove jobs directly? This sounds like the simplest way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I've decided to take the approach detailed at: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/WCF_windows_hosting.aspx

Basically, there will be an NT service which will host a WCF Library that contains all the functionality.  So, I'm now not bound by the 128 --> 256 restrictions in the OnCustomCommand function!